# Passing dictionary as argument to RobotFramework test

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I have a dictionary in my robot test that I want to be populated from the program that calls the test. I have two files: robotstarter.py and printdictionary.robot. However when I run the script the dictionary inside the test suite are all empty. I'm not sure whether this is a python or RobotFramework related issue.

[image: Result of running the script]

**robotstarter.py**

```
import robot

test_dict = {'dict.a': '2', 'dict.b': '2', 'dict.c': '2', 'dict.d': '2', 'dict.e': '2', 'dict.f': '2'}
print(test_dict)
robot.run("printdictionary.robot", variable=test_dict)
```

**printdictionary.robot**

```
*** Variables ***
&{dict}    a=${1}    b=${1}    c=${1}    d=${1}    e=${1}    f=${1}

*** Test Cases ***
Test print the identity stuff
    Log To Console     \nDictionary:
    Log To Console     ${dict.a}
    Log To Console     ${dict.b}
    Log To Console     ${dict.c}
    Log To Console     ${dict.d}
    Log To Console     ${dict.e}
    Log To Console     ${dict.f}
```

Comment: Why downvote? Please give feedback so I can fix the issue.

Comment: I might be missing something obvious here, but why should your python variable `test_dict` override the RF one `dict` - they have different names? Also, don't use language keywords like "dict" for names, you're redefining them in the local scope, and can't use the original one.

Comment: You could add {'dict.a ...} directly without declaring it first.  i.e. robot.run("printdictionary.robot", variable={'dict.a': '2', 'dict.b' ...}) but I thought that it was easier to read this way. To clarify, test_dict is just placeholder for the robot.run argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works by replacing the dictionary in robotstarter.py with an array.

`test_dict = {'dict.a': '2', 'dict.b': '2', 'dict.c': '2', 'dict.d': '2', 'dict.e': '2', 'dict.f': '2'}`

Becomes:

`test_dict = {'dict.a:2', 'dict.b:2', 'dict.c:2', 'dict.d:2', 'dict.e:2', 'dict.f:2'}`

Comment: Although this indeed will assign the value, it does not generate a real dictionary. Instead it creates 6 separate scalar variables.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a dictionary through the command line arguments variable is not supported. The [documentation on command line variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-variables-in-command-line) clearly states that only scalar variables are supported.

> ... Only scalar variables can be set using this syntax and they can
>   only get string values. ...

If you want to pass a hierarchy of any kind then that will have to be passed through a variable file. This can be a reference to a YAML file, but also a Python file declaring the dictionary, or a Python method/class that returns the required variables. Examples can be found in the [documentation on variable files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-file).

Comment: The restriction is true for the command line execution, but OP is calling the framework programmatically.