# Error: TypeError: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

**Framework:** Robot,
**Language:** Python-3.7.1
**Database Driver:** pyodc
**Proficicency:** Novice

I am trying to pass database connection configuration from python to robot framework and getting the below error message.

```
TypeError: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object
```

I tried to convert it into map before passing to robot but not helped.Also, have gone though similar error message discussions before writing here but none worked so for. Can someone assist the best solution on this case?

**Python:-**

Note: Each Key and value variables are string.

```
def databaseconfig(self, environment):
    if (environment == "QA"):
        database = {self.Key_Driver: self.Value_Driver,
                    self.Key_Server: self.Value_Server,
                    self.Key_Database: self.Value_Database,
                    self.Key_UID: self.Value_UID,
                    self.Key_PWD: self.Value_PWD,
                    self.Key_PORT: self.Value_Port
                    }
        return str(database)
```

**Robot file:-**

```
${connection}=  databaseconfig  QA
connect to database using custom params        pyodbc     ${connection}
```

**Expected:-**

Connection must establish successfully.

**Actual:**

Error: TypeError: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object

Comment: What are the data types behind `self.Key_Driver` and the rest?  Do they have `str` overloads? If not that is probably what is failing.  Please post the full error traceback as it will guide you directly to the issue.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Thanks for your response! The datatype of individual keys and drivers are 'String'. I have tried to send as dictionary and string but not worked. With respect to full error, i have received one line error only and that is what is being posted in description

Comment: Can you add the output to `print(str(database))`

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Here is the output of python. {'DRIVER': 'SQL Server', 'SERVER': 'foo', 'DATABASE': 'foo', 'UID': 'foo', 'PWD': 'foo', 'PORT': 'foo'}

Comment: add a `return str({})` outside your `if`. A function returns `None` by default which may be causing the issue.

Comment: I printed it before actual line of code in robot file and worked fine. So issue is something else...

Comment: You could maybe pass it differently [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49653090/8150685)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used this framework, but the docs suggest you may not be using the correct syntax for the parameter string: https://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.5/DatabaseLibrary.html#Connect%20To%20Database%20Using%20Custom%20Params

The example syntax they give here is `database='my_db_test', user='postgres', password='s3cr3t', host='tiger.foobar.com', port=5432`, rather than the string representation of a Python dictionary.

Can you see if it works if you replace `str(database)` with this code?

```
return ", ".join(
    "{}='{}'".format(a, b) for a,b in database.items()
)
```